# C# DateTimeOffset LocalDateTime vs ToLocalTime

Tags: c#, datetimeoffset

Can anyone explain the difference between the ToLocalTime() method and the LocalDateTime property in C# DateTimeOffset?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The docs state the following:

[`LocalDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.localdatetime?view=net-5.0):

> Gets a **DateTime** value that represents the local date and time of the current DateTimeOffset object.

[`ToLocalTime()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset.tolocaltime?view=net-5.0):

> Converts the current DateTimeOffset object to a **DateTimeOffset** object that represents the local time.

Looking at the [code](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs#L187-L201), we can see that the `LocalDateTime` property gets the value it represents as a UTC `DateTime` object and then converts it using the `DateTime` objects's `ToLocalTime()` method.

```
public DateTime UtcDateTime {
    [Pure]
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<DateTime>().Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc);
        return DateTime.SpecifyKind(m_dateTime, DateTimeKind.Utc);
    }
}

public DateTime LocalDateTime {
    [Pure]
    get {
        Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result<DateTime>().Kind == DateTimeKind.Local);
        return UtcDateTime.ToLocalTime();
    }
}
```

And we can see that [`.ToLocalTime()`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/mscorlib/system/datetimeoffset.cs#L694-L701) simply uses the same `UtcDateTime` property to retrieve the UTC `DateTime` object, again calls `ToLocalTime()` and then wraps it in a new `DateTimeOffset` object:

```
public DateTimeOffset ToLocalTime() {
    return ToLocalTime(false);
}

internal DateTimeOffset ToLocalTime(bool throwOnOverflow)
{
    return new DateTimeOffset(UtcDateTime.ToLocalTime(throwOnOverflow));
}
```

You can test the results with this code:

```
DateTimeOffset dto = new DateTimeOffset(2020, 10, 01, 9, 0, 0, 0, TimeSpan.FromHours(9));
Console.WriteLine(dto.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 10/01/2020 09:00:00 +09:00

DateTime localTimeDt = dto.LocalDateTime;
Console.WriteLine(localTimeDt.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 10/01/2020 02:00:00

DateTimeOffset localTimeDto = dto.ToLocalTime();
Console.WriteLine(localTimeDto.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 10/01/2020 02:00:00 +02:00
```

Naturally, the `DateTimeOffset` retains the +2:00 of the system time of Rextester since that's the timezone it's based in.

[Link to test](https://rextester.com/KRLFM68369)